# @ prefix for identifiers in C#

Tags: c#, .net

[The "@" character is allowed as a prefix to enable keywords to be used as identifiers.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670(v=vs.71).aspx)
Majority of .net developers know about this.

But what we may not know:
Two identifiers are considered the same if they are identical after the "@" prefix is removed.

So

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int x = 123;
    Console.WriteLine(@x);
}
```

is absolutely valid code and prints 123 to the console.

I'm curious why do we have such rule in the specs, and how this feature may be used in real world situations (it doesn't make sense to prefix identifiers with "@" if they are not keywords, right?).

Comment: oh your question was about why `@x` is valid. sorry i didnt got your question first. for the test you can also print `nameof(@x)` and you will see it prints `x`.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It is totally logical. `@` is not part of the name but is a special indicator to not treat what comes after as a keyword but as an identifier.

Comment: This is the only answer that directly addresses the question: the "@" is not part of the identifier, it only serves to "escape" the rest of the identifier.

Comment: In other words, it is a mandatory sigil which, as a special case, may be omitted if the name is unambiguously an identifier.

Answer (score 18):

Eric Lippert has a very good post about it: [Verbatim Identifier](http://ericlippert.com/2013/09/09/verbatim-identifiers/)

> I’m occasionally asked why it is that any identifier can be made into
>   a verbatim identifier. **Why not restrict the verbatim identifiers to
>   the reserved and contextual keywords?**
>
> The answer is straightforward. Imagine that we are back in the day
>   when C# 2.0 just shipped. You have a C# 1.0 program that uses yield
>   as an identifier, which is entirely reasonable; “yield” is a common
>   term in many business and scientific applications. Now, C# 2.0 was
>   carefully designed so that C# 1.0 programs that use yield as an
>   identifier are still legal C# 2.0 programs; it only has its special
>   meaning when it appears before return, and that never happened in a C#
>   1.0 program. But still, you decide that you’re going to mark the usages of yield in your program as verbatim identifiers so that it is
>   more clear to the future readers of the code that it is being used as
>   an identifier, not as part of an iterator

Answer (score 14):

Let's consider the example of a program that generates `C#` code -- for example, something that takes the columns in a database table and creates a comparable `C# POCO` object, with one property per column.

What if one of the column names matches a `C#` keyword?  The code generator doesn't have to remember which words are keywords or not if **all** of the property names are prefixed with `@`.
It's a fail-safe.  The extra `@` characters don't hurt the code at all!!

Comment: I think this is the right direction, there are some generic cases where you  might just run into using a keyword without being able to predict it before. T4 Templates are good example here.

Answer (score 7):

The other answers are pretty clear about why the behavior exists, but I think it might be worthwhile to look at the rules for which identifiers are treated as equal.

Quoting the specification section 2.4.2:

> Two identifiers are considered the same if they are identical after the following transformations are applied, in order:
>
> - The prefix "@", if used, is removed
> - Each *unicode-escape-sequence* is transformed into it's corresponding Unicode character.
> - Any *formatting-characters* are removed.

Following those rules, `@x` is identical to `x`.

Comment: I don't think this answer is very helpful. The OP is asking _why_ this is in the spec. He already knows that `@x` is identical to `x`.

Comment: @MatthewSainsbury - There were/are already 3 other answers that cover why the feature exists. This is intended to **supplement** those answers to add information about the rules for comparing identifiers. I added some text to clarify.

Answer (score 4):

It provides certainty:

- Using @word is future-proof. 

  No changes are needed if it becomes a keyword later.
- Most programmers will not be familiar with every keyword (C# has approx. 100 keywords)
- The more recent [keywords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx) are "contextual", so sometimes they are not keywords.

Comment: FWIW, C# currently has *exactly* 100 keywords (many of them contextual).  Though the addition of `nameof` in 6.0 will bring it to 101.

Comment: counted103 - a few are not mentioned in that Microsoft page e.g. "by"

Comment: Oh really?  My party/interview trick of being able to name all the keywords in alphabetical order (in 4 languages so far) may need to be updated...  (I go to weird parties...)